# ctx.filltext not showing anything?

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to draw the word hello on the canvas at 50, 50 but nothing shows up:

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000"> </canvas>

<script>

var ctx = document.getElementByID("ctx").getContext("2d");

//Draw some text at x50 y50
ctx.fillText('Hello',50,50);

</script>
```

Thanks for advice

Comment: try setting the font and fontsize beforehand? eg. `ctx.font = "20px serif";`

Answer (score 1):

Typo. It's `getElementbyId` with a lowercase `D`

Corrected code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
```

This is easily spotted if you're working in Google Chrome and have developer tools (`F12`) up and running. This would have returned a `document.getElementByID is not a function` error.